# Cannot view joomla component

Tags: joomla, components

I've created a joomla component which consists of a html form, and when I try and browse to it:

index.php?option=com_helloworld

I get an error 404, component cannot be found.

I'm following this tutuorial:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Can anyone please tell me how I can browse to the page?

UPDATE: here is the link to my sample component, its a basic html form.

http://tinyurl.com/d6tj7rz

Many thanks

Comment: paste your code in the question and make sure your component was installed correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that your component was installed successfully? On what step of tutorial you are now?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I am on the first page, where it states 'You can test this basic component by putting index.php?option=com_helloworld in your browser address (don't forget to prefix this address with your Joomla!2.5 installation path) after installing this component.' Nothing is displayed I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, even if a component is not installed correctly, you can still access the code if it's on the server, from my experience. But that may have been a 1.5 thing.

If you don't specify a view in the URL by passing &view=viewname, AND you haven't set a default fallback view, then you can't expect to have anything come up.

For a good example on how to set a default view, look in `components/com_contact/controller.php` line 38.

Within the main controller's display method:

```
// Set the default view name and format from the Request.
$vName = $this->input->get('view', 'categories');
$this->input->set('view', $vName);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your reply. Could you tell me how to setup a defaut view?

Comment: I've amended my answer to include that.

Comment: But it is not obligate to specify fallback view. When no task is given in the request variables, the default task will be executed. It's the display task by default. So the name of the folder (and class) of the default view is the name of the component itself. http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part

Comment: Many thanks, in the tutorial I linked to above, it doesn't state that. It explains how to create the file and folder, and a url to see the results. Is that correct?